# Tracking tire mileage in MAXIMO as measurements on meter readings

Tags: maximo

I am helping on a project and we are managing a tire warehouse in MAXIMO. That was OK, but now our business guys want us to track mileage for these tires. As these are stock parts, I do not understand how we can manage these and capture mileage for each tire.

Comment: Why do they want to track mileage for the tires? Is it to keep track of tire condition? Valuation of the tires in the warehouse? Are you selling individual used tires? Will they be used and returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rotating item is a serialized asset, such as a pump or a tire, that you define with a common item number. You designate an item as rotating because it shares properties of both items and assets. A rotating item can have an inventory value, metered mileage and an issue cost. 
A rotating item is an inventory item with a generic item number, a current balance, 
and multiple instances that can be used in various locations around a plant with individual asset numbers.
A rotating item cannot be consumed and is maintained as an asset. After creating an item and adding it to a storeroom, you can either use the Assets application to create the asset record for the item you want to track, or create a purchase order for the rotating item and serialize it when you receive it.
When you associate an asset with a rotating item, balances can be displayed and tracked for the item. A rotating item is tracked both by its item number in Inventory records and by its asset number in Assets records. An item cannot be both a spare part and a rotating item.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using rotating asset/item. It is too complicated to use and very difficult to train on. Many people recommend it as a solution, but in practice, all the customers I've worked with don't like it. Eventually, they learn it but the work flow is completely different from issues and returns. Wait until you have to move the asset from a storeroom to location or vice versa.

You can use item condition code if you want to tires and what percentage tread is left: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/understanding-condition-codes